# Symbology based on related table ArcMap10.5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, attribute-table, relates

I have a parcels layer and related table of water meters. I did labeling of water meters IDs and I pulled it from the related table through the script.

Can I symbolize polygons based on related table records?

So far I was able to do that through joining tables, but it is not ideal for the end user they do not want those tables together.

I read it is possible in ArcGIS Online, but I am working in ArcMap 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older but I'm working in this as well. So far it should work like this. Do your table relate then open the attribute table and click the related tables button which is two offset tables with arrows point to each other. Switch to your related table and then you should be able to style based on that. I have it working in one scenario but not another in the same map.